# flexbox space-between and align right

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a div with 1 to 3 items and I want them to behave like this :

1. Three items : take the whole line with `justify-content: space-between`

   ```
   +-----------+
   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
   +-----------+
   ```
2. If there is only 1 item, align it to the right.

   ```
   +-----------+
   |       | 3 |
   +-----------+
   ```

Here's my code :

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Styling only */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container div {
  /* Styling only */
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

I've found a solution with `direction: rtl`, but I hope there's a less hacky solution, and I prefer not to reorder my dom.

Any ideas?

Comment: direction: rtl is not a hack actually.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is a selector for that.

```
.container div:only-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Styling only */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container div {
  /* Styling only */
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 10px;
}
.container div:only-child {
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact, using `margin-left: auto` was sufficient, even without the `only-child` slector. Thanks!

Comment: In my testing, using `margin-left: auto` on the last child causes all the earlier children to be pushed far left as if they were all `justify-content: flex-start`, so `only-child` is the actual solution. [codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aEwrpz)

Comment: There is an issue with this for the scenario where there is one visible child, and the other children use `display: none` instead of being completely removed from the dom -- `:only-child` will not work in that case.

Comment: No reason why it should....the question in no way references `display:none` and if it had an alternative solution would have been appropriate.  CSS selects elements in the DOM regardless of whether they are visible or not.

Comment: This is so counterintuitive. I was searching for this forever. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: This does not work with right to left reading order. You can use `margin-inline-start`, but it would be better if the flexbox spec had a solution for this beyond `row-reverse`, which I think is actually the most correct solution.

Comment: @HugoH `margin-left: auto` alone *is insufficient* if you actually want to retain the effect of allocating usable space between items. When you set a left margin to `auto`, the otherwise free space between items in the now right aligned container *collapses*, so your `justify-content: space-between` rule becomes useless -- it applies, but there is no free space to distribute between items anyway. Be precise when you say "was sufficient" -- it may have been sufficient for *your* use case, but make no mistake -- CSS does what you tell it to. Maybe you didn't need any space between, after all?

Answer (score 15):

Use flex-direction property

```
.container {
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction:row-reverse;
  /* Styling only */
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.container div {
  /* Styling only */
  background: white;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div>
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this reorders the DOM, which OP did not want to do. If there are multiple items, the cells ordered [1, 2, 3] would instead be ordered [3, 2, 1].

Answer (score -5):

**Change from this**

```
.container {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

**TO**

```
.container {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: This will only align to right but removes space between